# How do you format Microsoft Access' Date/Time Extended to Date/Time when linked to the SQL Server DateTime2(0) datatype?

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, ms-access

I am trying to link an Access database to a SQL Server backend that has a DateTime2(0) field.

I am currently upsizing the database to SQL Server and would like to use the recommended datatype.

I use the dates in the Access Date/Time datatype all throughout my program, and I would prefer to not have to do a ton of string manipulation to get it to work. I know I could rework everything to use passthroughs, but would prefer to use the linked tables for now.

Comment: This could work as a workaround, but I'd prefer to find a direct solution, so that I can use the date/time format. cdate(left(rs!dateCreated,instr(rs!dateCreated,".")-1))

Comment: I believe Access stores dates as OADates, meaning it stores them internally as a decimal number where the integer portion is the number of days since 1899-12-31 and the decimal portion is the time. The easiest way to translate those dates to sql is to use `datetime` since `datetime` basically uses OADates under the covers. However due to some ancient beef between excel and the rest of the world, SQL stores OADates as time since 1900-01-01. So you might need to add two to your dates.

Comment: Here's the docs for Access dates: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/store-calculate-compare-datetime-data That page gives the example of 36298.5833333333 being 1999-05-18 whereas if you run `select cast(36298.5833333 as datetime)` in sql server, you get 1999-05-20

Comment: @Xedni Oof I was hoping that wasn't the answer. I think I'll have to either switch to the datetime or do passthrough formatting. Thanks.

Comment: Use _DateTime_ as the field type if at all possible, and it will save you from a lot of trouble. Access queries can read _DateTime2_ in queries, but VBA doesn't anything about it, thus converts to text.

Comment: @June7 I don't think that's an appropriate duplicate. Date/Time Extended is a new data type that has been added in Access 2021 and recent builds of 365, see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-the-date-time-extended-data-type-708c32da-a052-4cc2-9850-9851042e0024.

Comment: @June7 it kind of does, but similar to what Erik A said, it is slightly different. That is also 12 years old and things are mildly different.